# ExpertPdf.HtmlToPdf using lots of memory

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

While trying to generate a pdf using ExpertPdf.HtmlToPdf, it's using a lot of memory. Does anyone know how to reduce the memory usage?

Comment: Stop generating :)! ! ,Jokes aside please update with relevant code and relevant scenario. Only in these context can some one help you

Comment: Agreed, without posting any code we can't help you.

Comment: What makes you think it's using lots of memory in the first place?

Comment: Use Web to PDF RestApi http://www.convertapi.com No more out of memory :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess it was some thing to do with ie 7.I upgraded my browser to ie 8 and it solved the issue.